How to unit test asynchronous Combine based code without XCTestExpectation or fixed waiting times
In iOS development using Swift, what options do I have for testing code that utilizes the Combine framework? Specifically, I'm looking to test a function that returns an AnyPublisher asynchronously. I prefer not to use expectations or any approaches that require specifying a waiting time. Are there methodologies similar to async/await code testing that I can use?
Here's an example of the function I need to test:
import Combine

func fetchData() -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
    // Assume this is some asynchronous network call returning AnyPublisher
    someAsyncCall.
        .map(\.data)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

I am interested in understanding how to test the fetchData function effectively using best practices for Combine

Why don’t you want to use expectation? (FWIW, expectations aren’t specifying a “wait” time, but rather a max timeout in case the expectation is not satisfied within a reasonable timeframe.)

Asynchronous code needs asynchronous testing.

From my experience expectation may work in reasonable timeframe on local machine but fail in Cloud.

Generally one would either bump up the timeout to something appropriate for your use-case or, if extremely slow, we’d mock that third-party dependency. Personally, I’d advise against removing the timeout altogether (like the accepted answer does).

Yeah, I totally agree. It's also worth mentioning that the new Swift testing framework allows us to explicitly set a timeout using @Suite(.timeLimit(.minutes(1))) or @Test(.timeLimit(.minutes(1))).
